Invalid custom control data source modification interface
There is a custom control
     <ctrls:SearchDefalut Source="{Binding SearchResults}"
                          Height="40" Width="180"/>


I have a dependent property called Source
       public IEnumerable Source
       {
           get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
           set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
       }

       // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
       public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(SearchDefalut), new PropertyMetadata(null,OnMySourcePropertyChanged));

       private static void OnMySourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       {
         //TODO
       }


When I use the command to trigger the SearchResults add or remove data dependency property OnMySourcePropertyChanged Source will not be call it makes me feel very confused
     <ctrls:SearchDefalut Source="{Binding SearchResults,Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Height="40" Width="180"/>


<ctrls:SearchDefalut Source="{Binding SearchResults,Mode=OneWaySource}"
                          Height="40" Width="180"/>


So I tried to change the Mode but it still didn't work

The Source property does not change when you modify the collection that it holds. You need to check if the collection implements INotifyCollectionChanged and attach a CollectionChanged event handler. See the answers to the duplicate questions.

You may also want to check spelling. Defalut is certainly meant to be Default.

SearchResult use CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Com ponentModel ObservableProperty marks in package

And when I was in the viewmodel initialization for the assignment based on attribute OnMySourcePropertyChanged Source can be triggered calls; When I changed SearchResults while the program was running, the dependent methods didn't get called, which confused me

Sure, but that is not sufficient for notifying the UI when you only add or remove elements without assigning a new collection instance. Use an ObservableCollection in the view model and attach a CollectionChanged handler in the view.

The SearchResults in my Viewmodel are of type ObservableCollection

Then just do what's shown in the duplicates.

Each time the data is new, and I first clear the previous data

Sure, but you do not assign a new collection instance, so that the PropertyChangedCallback is not called.

I understand what you mean, but I have a puzzle. Isn't the ObservableCollection type can be dynamically inserted and then updated to the UI display, so each insertion should call PropertyChangedCallback to update to the UI display

No, that is a misconception. UI elements with IEnumerable dependency properties (like ItemsControl) attach INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged event handlers.

oh, I am very glad to get your answer, so that I can correct my wrong opinion
